# WordPress dashboard: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: wp-admin, login, dashboard, youtube

I've just watched this video: [Create and Host a Wordpress Website on AWS EC2 with your own domain name! - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Uofkq718n8)

I followed every step other then the one adding your own domain (because I don't have one right now), but when I want to access /wp-admin it throws me an error:

> Not Found - the requested URL was not found on this server.

How can I fix this error?

It worked before I moved the default WordPress page as default.